# Non-orthogonal bases

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

a set of functions $$ u_{n}=x^n, n=0,1,2....$$ is linearly independent, but it isn't orthonormal. I need to find the first four polynomials that are orthonormal and the interval $$-1\leqslant x \leqslant 1$$

(these polynomials are proportional to the Legendre polynomials)

Is there a method to find those polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you want is Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.
The inner product used here is $$<P_m(x), P_n(x)> = \int_{-1}^{1}P_m(x)P_n(x)dx$$, which you want to be zero when you combine two of your final functions.
Let the first function $P_0 = v_1 = 1$.
Then the second function will be $$ v_2 = x - \frac{<x,1>}{<1,1>} \cdot 1$$
The third function will be
$$v_3 = x^2 - \frac{<x^2,1>}{<1,1>} \cdot v_1-\frac{<x^2,v_2>}{<v_2,v_2>} \cdot v_2$$. and so on.
If you need orthonormal, not just orthogonal, divide each vector by its length, $\sqrt{<v,v>}$ as you find them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I have a question for you, this method only works for non-orthogonal bases?

Comment: If your basis is already orthogonal, the parts you subtract will all be zero and your vectors will be unchanged (except for having unit length if you choose to do that.)